# Ellipsoids as surfaces of revolution and their geodesics

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemann-surfaces, geodesic

I'm trying to find the geodesics on an ellipsoid and I have a few questions..

First to begin I am trying to understand the different types of ellipsoids. I would have liked to approach finding the geodesics using Clairaut's relation so I'm wondering if all ellipsoids are surfaces of revolution.

I know there are cases: for an ellipsoid centered at the origin with equation $\frac{x^2}{a^2} +\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2} = 1$ 
and parametric equation $\textbf{x}(u,v) = (a\cos(u)\sin(v),b\sin(u)\sin(v),c\cos(v))$ where $u \in [0,2\pi), v \in [0,\pi)$ so as a surface of revolution I'm taking my equation to be $f(v)= (0, \sin(v),\cos(v))$ $v \in [0,\pi)$ and then rotating it.

1) the sphere which I'm not so concerned about since I know it's geodesics are great circles.

2) The case where a = b and c is different

3) The case where a,b < c

4) The case where a,b > c

So I'm just wondering can all these cases be generalized to surfaces of revolution...

From there I am going to solve the geodesic equations which I know is a problem in it of itself, but really I just want to know is looking at the geodesics in these 4 cases is a good way to start and also if the way I'm looking at the ellipsoid as a surface of revolution is correct... (I'm guessing in the last two cases is where I have an issue)

Comment: Radial symmetry about some axis is required for a surface of revolution. This symmetry is obvious when any of the semiaxis lengths are equal. Can you find such an axis if they are distinct?

Comment: @amd so is a,b,c are distinct this is technically still an ellipsoid just not an ellipsoid of revolution?